# cant install yaml-cpp because it conflicts with yaml-cpp?

Tags: apt, dpkg

It appears that no yaml-cpp is installed

```
sudo apt-get remove yaml-cpp
Package yaml-cpp is not installed, so not removed
```

But when I try to install yaml-cpp I can not because apt-get all of a sudden remembers an old version of yaml-cpp that now conflicts.

```
sudo apt-get install yaml-cpp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yaml-cpp
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 577 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main yaml-cpp i386 0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000 [205 kB]
Fetched 205 kB in 0s (237 kB/s)   
(Reading database ... 342813 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking yaml-cpp (from .../yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/yaml-cpp/emitter.h', which is also in package yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev 0.2.6-4~oneiric
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/yaml-cpp_0.2.7-5precise-20120502-0513-+0000_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove  yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev

```
apt-get remove yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev
```

Comment: Do you always have to specify the version number when removing packages? It is odd to me that it says "package not installed" instead of "please pick a version to remove"

Comment: No, for some reason, that was the full package name. That shouldn't happen and points to a messed up package.